# How to bypass missing link and continue to scrape good data?

Tags: python, ubuntu

How to bypass missing link and continue to scrape good data?

I am using Python2 and Ubuntu 14.04.3.

I am scraping a web page with multiple links to associated data.
Some associated links are missing so I need a way to bypass the missing links and continue scraping.

```
Web page 1
    part description 1 with associated link
    part description 2 w/o associated link
    more part descriptions with and w/o associcated links
Web page n+
    more part descriptions
```

I tried:

```
try:
    Do some things.
    Error caused by missing link.

except Index Error as e:
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
    break # to go on to next link. 
    # Did not work because program stopped to report error!
```

Since link is missing on web page can not use if missing link statement.

Thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: Program does not stop if exception is caught. Make sure you handle exception within your link loop and you do actually catch exceptions. Also provide complete error message and MVCE.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
import urllib

def get_content_safe(url):
    try:
        contents = urllib.open(url)
        return contents
    except IOError, ex:
        # Report ex your way
        return None
    
def scrape:
    # ....
    content = get_content_safe(url)
    if content == None:
        pass # or continue or whatever
    # ....
```

Long story short, just like [Basilevs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125562/basilevs) said, when you catch exception, your code will not break and will keep its execution.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected my faulty except error by following Python 2 documentation. Except correction jumped faulty web site missing link and continued on scraping data.

Except correction:

```
    except:
        # catch AttributeError: 'exceptions.IndexError' object has no attribute 'errno'
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print "Error: %s" % e
        break
```

I will look into the answer(s) posted to my questions.

Thanks again for your help!